# MySQL - row filter replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I've been having a hard time to figure out how to configure distributed database system in MySQL. I have 3 servers, each has the same database model. I have configured them for using replication - so there is 1 Master and 2 Slaves. Everything works fine, but what I want to do next is to "filter" replication data.

Let's say that I have two tables: customers and products. I want to replicate all content of products table to both slaves (and I got this part), but I want to replicate customers from Europe to Slave1 and from Asia to Slave2. So master will contain all information about customers, but slaves only some part of it. How can I achive that?

As far as I know replication itself doesn't support this kind of filtering. I am not sure, but it seems like partitioning is not an answer as well.

Are there any build-in mechanizm in MySQL that may help? If not, how would you resolve this situation?

Comment: How to resolve it (or if there are other options) depends on your setup and especially on your requirements, so the reason why you are doing it/what you want to achieve by doing it. E.g.: can you live with just hiding the data on the different slaves or do you do it for privacy/saving bandwith/optimization reasons? Are you using statement or row based replication? Are your slaves read-only (so changes will not get back to the master)?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use custom way to read data and based on your business logic add data to slave 1 or slave 2.

For instance, you can read change in database entry from **binlog** and based on your input data, you can store it in different slave databases. However, there might be a small delay in this.

There is a very good system which does the same, ie maxwell(https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell) which uses kafka to push database change event with type of query and old and new data. Now on the basis of that you can write kafka consumer to read data and push it into your slave databases. maxwell uses binlog replicator same as Master/Slave replicator and is reliable.